# ASP .NET Core disposing UnitOfWork before getting all data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm implementing a generic repository + Unit of work pattern along with a WebApi project. I'm having problems with getting one entity and including the collection of another enttity that refers to it.

I have the following entities mapped through code first:

```
public class Ingredient : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public Guid RecipeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

This is my unit of work:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IRepositoryFactory, IUnitOfWork<TContext>, IUnitOfWork where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TContext context;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> repositories;

    public UnitOfWork(TContext context)
    {
        this.context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    public TContext Context => context;

    public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        if (repositories == null)
        {
            repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        }

        var type = typeof(TEntity);
        if (!repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            repositories.Add(type, new Repository<TEntity>(context));
        }
        return (IRepository<TEntity>)repositories[type];
    }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And my generic repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly DbContext dbContext;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        dbContext = context;
        dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public T GetEntity(Guid id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public T GetEntity(Guid id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> properties = GetProperties(includeProperties);

        IQueryable<T> queryable = dbSet;

        foreach (var property in includeProperties)
        {
            queryable = dbSet.Include(property);
        }

        return queryable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    [...]

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetProperties(Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        List<string> includelist = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in includeProperties)
        {
            MemberExpression body = item.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (body == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("The body must be a member expression");

            includelist.Add(body.Member.Name);
        }
        return includelist.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

The controller is injecting the RecipeService. In the controller I have this method:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
        var recipe = recipeService.GetRecipe(id);
        if (recipe == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(recipe);
    }
```

The recipe service injects the IUnitOfWork and has the following method:

```
    public Recipe GetRecipe(Guid id)
    {
        return repository.GetEntity(id, r => r.Ingredients);
    }
```

Also I have the services registered as follows:

```
        services.AddScoped<IRepositoryFactory, UnitOfWork<TContext>>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork<TContext>>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork<TContext>, UnitOfWork<TContext>>();
        services.AddScoped<IRecipeService, RecipeService>();
```

My problem is when I'm getting a specified recipe(along with its ingredients) i got a "The connection has been restarted" error (in firefox). While debugging I can see that I have the recipe with its ingredients. But when returning Ok(recipe) and mapping the result to the entities, the IUnitOfWork is disposed after getting the first ingredient.

Anyone can help me out? Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using an ORM like EF? It's impossible to guess why *you* implementation of an ORM fails. With EF I'd say that you tried to use lazy loading after closing a connection. `"The connection has been restarted"` isn't an ASP.NET or EF error either. Your application probably crashed for some reason. Add proper exception handling and logging, debug your code and identify what line throws and what the actual exception is

Comment: BTW the Repository pattern was created *before* LINQ and EF. Your repository code is trying to do what *EF* already does - map properties to row fields. The end result is the code is *more* complex and finding bugs is harder. Your actual Repository is `RecipeService` at this point, not `GenericRepository<Recipe>`. `GetRecipe` is just a wrapper over what could easily be `someContext.Recipes.FirstOrDefault(rcp=>rcp.ID==id)` or `someContext.Recipes.Include(r=>r.Ingredients).FirstOrDefault(rcp=>rcp.ID==id)`

Comment: Finally `return repository.GetEntity(id, r => r.Ingredients);` what is the lifetime of `repository` and who controls the underlying *connection*? Are ingredients loaded lazily perhaps? Are you trying to use them in a *view*? At this point the controller action has finished and the repository has been disposed. You'd need to use eager loading in this case

Comment: Hi, I'm using EF and following guides to implement a generic repository pattern with EF

Comment: I'm not using eager loading as i'm specifically including the Ingredients. The repository lifetime is scoped as is handled by the UnitOfWork

Comment: "Specifically loading" *is* the definition of eager loading and the code you posted doesn't show that anywhere. No `Include` calls, no attempt to find related objects by reflection. Saying that the UOW controls the repository is information-free too. *Who* controls the UoW? *Where* does the exception or error occur?

Comment: In the method public T GetEntity(Guid id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) I'm including the includeProperties

Comment: Which you don't need because that's the job of EF. And that's about *properties*, not related objects. You aren't eagerly loading anything

Comment: That method is then called in the RecipeService

Comment: *Where does the exception occur? What is its call stack?* Anyway, if you want to solve this, remove all this code and use a simple DbContext instance. Once you get that working, add more code. Right now it's not possible to reproduce the unspecified problem without a *lot* of guesswork and effort

Comment: The problem is I'm not getting any exception. Also I'm pretty sure i'm not using lazy loading beacuse if I wasn't including the property (Ingredients) its value would be null (as I was getting earlier)

Comment: All i can see is while debugging and after getting to the first ingredient, it seems to try to load the Recipe again, because of the virtual Recipe property, maybe a circular reference?

Comment: Yes it was a circular reference problem while serializing to JSon, I don't now why it doesn't rhow an exception. I soved it by ignorence the reference loop in the json options. Is there maybe a better way?

Comment: ASP.NET Core uses JSON.NET which *does* throw if it detects a circular reference. EF though returns *dynamic* proxy classes so JSON.NET may or may not detect this. If it doesn't you could end up with a StackOverflowException or runaway recursion. There are a lot of fixes for these issues, including *not* using the EF entities as DTOs and definitely not returning them as API results. Tha'ts another problem with this UoW/Repository implementation. It's still EF with a lot of complexity on top. It doesn't even map the EF proxy classes to DTOs

Comment: Yes, my next step is to add DTOs to get only the data I need for each request. Thank you for your help

Comment: As someone said about APIs, `Your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model `

Comment: Nice saying, i'll remember it ;)

Comment: Totally agree with @PanagiotisKanavos.  I left a comment the other day about the use of unnecessary wrapper classes to implement patterns that are already implemented for you.  `DbContext` is unit of work and `DbSet` is generic repository.  Inject your DbContext into the service layer and free yourself from this extra complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Brad, this was just a test project to see how a repository pattern could be implemented in asp .net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was having a circular reference i wasn't getting any exception.

I fixed by adding the following in the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class:

```
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```